# Node JS async middleware not catching exception

Tags: node.js

I have a middleware async function in NodeJS as such.

```
module.exports = function (handler) {
return async (req, res, next) => {
try {
  console.log('async called...');
  await handler(req, res);
}
catch(ex) {
  console.log('catch...');
  next(ex);
  }
 };  
}
```

This is my route handler.

```
const asyncMiddleware = require('../middleware/async');

router.get('/', asyncMiddleware(async (req, res) => {
 await db.query('SELECT * xxx FROM aircraft LIMIT 10', 
function (err, rows, fields) {  
    if(err) throw err;
    res.send(rows)
 })
}));
```

The issue is when i call the route handler with the invalid syntax to simulate an exception the catch of the middle ware is not catching the exception from the throw err in the route.

When I call the route i get
async called...
but no
catch...
on the console.

Anyone know why this would be?